# Mostrar histograma para valores concretos

Tags: python, numpy

Supongamos que tenemos un vector con 200 enteros aleatorios, elegidos en el intervalo (1,20):

```
import pandas as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v1= np.random.randint(1,21,200)
```

Quiero resolver dos problemas:

1. Crear un histograma solo para los valores 5,6,8,14,16,19.
2. Crear un histograma con los 3 valores más repetidos sin contar la moda.

1.He empezado creando un simple histograma para v1:

```
plt.hist(v1, edgecolor='black', bins=20)
plt.show()
```

Para continuar creando un vector con bincount donde cada elemento me dice el número de veces que se repite el número correspondiente con la posición del elemento en el vector:

```
cuenta = np.bincount(v1)
```

Y quedarme con los de la posición 5,6,8,14,16,19:

```
resumen = cuenta[np.array([5,6,8,14,16,19])]
```

Pero claro, de este modo no sabré que la primera posición de *resumen* se corresponde con el 5, la segunda con el 6, la tercera con el 8, etc...
Y si hago:

```
plt.hist(resumen)
```

No consigo lo que busco.

2.Podría quedarme con el máximo (moda) de *cuenta*:

```
np.argmax(cuenta)
```

Tendría la moda, pero nada más. Necesitaría los siguientes 3 valores más repetidos y representarlos en el histograma.

Les agradezco su ayuda.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo es usar `collections.Counter` para hacer el recuento. Este te retorna un diccionario cuyas claves son los datos y los valores el número de veces que se repite cada uno:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

v1= np.random.randint(1,21,200)
cuenta = Counter(v1)
```

El resultado en `cuenta` es el diccionario:

```
{2: 18, 11: 17, 17: 13, 5: 12, 10: 11, 19: 11, 16: 11, 
 3: 11, 18: 10, 20: 10, 15: 9, 1: 9, 8: 9, 4: 9, 
 13: 8, 7: 8, 6: 8, 9: 6, 12: 6, 14: 4}
```

De aquí puedes extraer lo que te interese a otro diccionario, por ejemplo así:

```
elegidos = [5,6,8,14,16,19]
resumen = {k: v for k,v in cuenta.items() if k in elegidos}
```

que nos dará:

```
{5: 12, 6: 8, 8: 9, 14: 4, 16: 11, 19: 11}
```

Para pintar esto puedes usar `matplotlib`, el diagrama `bar`, así:

```
plt.bar(x=resumen.keys(), height=resumen.values())
```

[image: Resultado]

pero como ves eso te deja "huecos" entre barras, para los datos no presentes en tu selección. Si no los quieres, creo que lo más sencillo es hacerlo a través de Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(resumen, orient="index").sort_index().plot(kind="bar")
```

[image: con pandas]

Además `Counter()` te sirve también para obtener los tres más frecuentes:

```
>>> cuenta.most_common(4)
[(2, 18), (11, 17), (17, 13), (5, 12)]
```

Donde vemos que el más frecuente es el 2 (la moda, que puedes descartar) y los tres siguientes son el 11 (repetido 17 veces), el 17 (13 veces) y el 5 (12 veces).

Dices que quieres representar estos tres valores en el histograma, pero aquí ya me pierdo ¿En cuál? ¿Marcarlos de otro color en el histograma global? ¿Otro histograma aparte? ¿Añadirlos al histograma de los "elegidos"?

### Actualización

Otra forma de pintar con matplotlib los resultados **sin necesidad de pandas** es convertir los valores del eje X en cadenas. De este modo considerará esa variable "categorical" y no dejará huecos.

Es decir, una vez tenemos el diccionario `resumen`, con por ejemplo estos valores:
`{5: 12, 6: 8, 8: 9, 14: 4, 16: 11, 19: 11}`, lo ordenaríamos por claves (pues un diccionario en general tiene orden aleatorio), extraeríamos esas claves y las convertiríamos en cadenas para que sean una variable categórica, dejándolos en una lista llamada por ejemplo `eje_x`, y extraeríamos los correspondientes valores dejándolos en otra lista llamada por ejemplo `eje_y`, así:

```
eje_x = [str(k) for k in sorted(resumen)]
eje_y = [resumen[k] for k in sorted(resumen)]
```

Los contenidos de estas variables serían en este ejemplo:

```
>>> eje_x
['5', '6', '8', '14', '16', '19']
>>> eje_y
[12, 8, 9, 4, 11, 11]
```

Y ahora `plt.bar()` ya lo pintará bien:

```
plt.bar(x=eje_x, height=eje_y, width=1, edgecolor="black")
```

[image: Resultado]

Esta misma técnica puedes usarla para pintar los "top 3" (excluyendo la moda), pero teniendo en cuenta que lo que te retorna `most_common()` es una lista de tuplas, en vez de un diccionario. Asi que, por ejemplo:

```
top3 = cuenta.most_common(4)[1:]  # El  [1:] es para excluir al primero
eje_x = [ str(d[0]) for d in sorted(top3) ]
eje_y = [ d[1] for d in sorted(top3) ]
plt.bar(x=eje_x, height=eje_y, width=1, edgecolor="black")
```

[image: Top3]

Comment: Genial. Muchas gracias, abulafia. Represento cuenta.most_common(4) con un plt.bar y listo.

Comment: @DomingoÁlvarezPalas Si, pero conviene "preprocesar" un poco el resultado para que las etiquetas en el eje X salgan ordenadas y no haya huecos (si es que te interesa hacerlo así). He ampliado la respuesta para mostrar cómo

Comment: muchas gracias. Queda genial.